Gnosis Safe API always returning `isExecuted` as false?
I am using the Safe SDK and i've noticed that no matter what I do, the transactions isExecuted status does not seem to update. It's always false. If I execute the transaction in the Gnosis Safe UI, everything seems to work, but when I grab the transaction via the api, isExecuted is always false and isSuccessful is always undefined.
In fact, there are no differences in the returned object from those API calls from when an transaction is pending to after it is executed. The only thing that changes is that transaction is no longer returned from the getPendingTransactions call and is only returned in getAllTransactions.
Only target Base right now. Example payload that gets sent in the propose transactions call is:
curl 'https://safe-transaction-base.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x23aB97a41C10De15C4432D3F2eaE9C84c5734695/multisig-transactions/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"to":"0x34AB004894D81ba5E35e7bAA801AbCf4213dc90A","value":"0","data":"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","operation":0,"baseGas":"0","gasPrice":"0","gasToken":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","refundReceiver":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","nonce":14,"safeTxGas":"0","contractTransactionHash":"0xe8643324652762c3a0a77aa8d6dfed842e82b3bb0840b5b30015d9a5e2be04ef","sender":"0x8c5Cb9005a5d48db56eCD895F4e43F74136EfDCd","signature":"0xc3bf4367426f508c3d2ae96dca2ca8497af586ecc79b1f89c94d2201d1032e5e599d90d0d1cb6837697ae49dd05b061938b22fb11172836909e19d4d9bb4fdc220"}'

Example curl for calling confirmTransaction on that transaction is:
curl 'https://safe-transaction-base.safe.global/api/v1/multisig-transactions/0xe9150dc7daeebc9146f745525eb35c785d715545e6ffd3144be239d13890e915/confirmations/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"signature":"0x0bec8fd2501f1015b122ab060ae73d6b4538734be87f7aa8213463887299ba7975eaab10683fe309879877d718358ddf6046f4829c2be54429e6007353e4a5bb20"}'

The the curls from calling executeTransactionare the following:
curl 'https://mainnet.base.org/' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":10,"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"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","to":"0xca11bde05977b3631167028862be2a173976ca11"},"latest"]}'

and
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0xffa1ad74","to":"0x23aB97a41C10De15C4432D3F2eaE9C84c5734695"},"latest"],"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":20}'

Any ideas?

This looks like a bug. What endpoints and what networks are you targeting? Would you care to also provide the payload that you are sending, along with previous information? Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

@Louis-SafeCoreTeam i've updated the post with that information. Thanks for helping!
